# Classic ASP encryption

Tags: asp.net, encoding, character-encoding

The below code for encryption of text is running fine in classic ASP page when it is included in ASP.NET website but throws an error when I am running in IIS:

```
Dim encData_byte As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( Request("txtPassword"))
Dim encodedData As String = Convert.ToBase64String(encData_byte)
```

Error is triggered by the first line above:

> An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator. If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error.

Comment: An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.

If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error.

Comment: Dim encData_byte As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( Request("txtPassword"))  On this line

Comment: System.Text.Encoding and Convert.ToBase64String mean something in .net but not in classic.  If you use the include file directive then the included file becomes part of the page in which it is included, so asp.net code will work in an include file,whatever the file extension, as long as the file extension of the page in which it is included is .aspx

Comment: Encoding and encryption are separate terms and mean rather different things, check out the tag descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

the error you are getting is not the real one. it is just a message from the server.
you need to allow "send error to browser"
Control Panel\Administrative Tools
Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager —> Default Web Site —> ASP -> debugging properties
and set  send error to browser = true

this will show you the real error and the line..

or you can contact your server tech support and ask them to do so.

here is an easy way to encrypt in ASP

```
Function encodeString(input)
 Dim newStr : newStr = ""
 for i = 1 to len(input)
  newStr = newStr & chr((asc(mid(input,i,1))+8))
 next
 encodeString = newStr
End Function

and decrypt:

Function decodeString(input)
 Dim oldStr : oldStr = ""
 for i = 1 to len(input)
  oldStr = oldStr & chr((asc(mid(input,i,1))-8))
 next
 decodeString = oldStr
End Function
```

**it is not the best and fastest way but it is simple and works**

hop this helps